# The limit of the average value of two sequences

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

I have a question about the following task:

Let $a_n$ and $b_n$ be sequences for which: $lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=a$ and $lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=b$. Show that the limit
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\cfrac{a_1b_n+a_2b_{n-1}+\dots+a_{n-1}b_2 + a_nb_1}{n}=ab
$$

I already tried:
$$
\left|\cfrac{a_1b_n+a_2b_{n-1}+\dots+a_{n-1}b_2 + a_nb_1}{n} - ab\right|=
$$
$$
=\left|\cfrac{(a_1b_n-ab)+(a_2b_{n-1}-ab)+\dots+(a_{n-1}b_2-ab) + (a_nb_1-ab)}{n} \right|\le
$$
$$
\le \left|\cfrac{a_1b_n-ab}{n} \right|+\left|\cfrac{a_2b_{n-1}-ab}{n} \right|+\dots+\left|\cfrac{a_nb_1-ab}{n} \right|
$$
But from there I have no idea have I can find such $N$ for each $\varepsilon$ so that this sum is smaller than $\varepsilon$ to show that it converges to $ab$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint.* Write
$$\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^na_k\,b_{n+1-k}-ab
=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n(a_k-a)\,(b_{n+1-k}-b)
+b\cdot\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n(a_k-a)+a\cdot\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n(b_k-b).
$$
The two last terms tend to $0$ by Cesàro's theorem. It remains to show that
$$\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n(a_k-a)\,(b_{n+1-k}-b)=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}(a_k-a)(b_{n+1-k}-b)+\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^{n-\lfloor n/2\rfloor}(a_{n+1-k}-a)(b_k-b)$$
tend to $0$. Take $N$ large so that $|a_m-a|\le\varepsilon$ and $|b_m-b|\le\varepsilon$ for all $m\ge N$. This implies that for all $n>2N$ and $2k\le n+1$, $|a_{n+1-k}-a|\le\varepsilon$ and $|b_{n+1-k}-b|\le\varepsilon$.